Unable to see the "File" dialog step in Einstein Bot Dialog
I am using Einstein Bot and it has some dialogs.
I want bot to send a static file to chat visitor and I am following this Salesforce Help Article
I have created asset and provided all necessary permissions.
I am not able to see "File" dialog step when setting up the Dialog. Am I missing something?
